# Trying to pass array of coordinates to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass coordinates to a UIViewController. How would I would be able to accessing them.  Here is the code for the TableViewController

```
class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController
```

{

```
let fruits = ["London", "Melbourne", "Singapore", "Brazil", "Germany"]
let locations: [[Double]] = [[51.50722, -0.12750],[-37.8136, 144.9631],[-23.5475000,-46.6361100],[49.3297,8.57428],[45.58005,9.27246]]
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Segues

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
            let location = locations[indexPath.row]


            (segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController).detailItem = fruit
            (segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController).coordinateItem = location
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0){

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = fruit
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
```

}
This is the code for the UIViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var currentTemperatureLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var currentHumidityLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var currentPrecipitationLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var currentWeatherIcon: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var currentWeatherSummary: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?
@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel?

// Location coordinates
var coordinate: (lat: Double, lon: Double) = (37.8267,-122.423)

// TODO: Enter your API key here
private let forecastAPIKey = ""

var coordinateItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}
var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
        label.text = detail.description
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()
    retrieveWeatherForecast()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func retrieveWeatherForecast() {
    let forecastService = ForecastService(APIKey: forecastAPIKey)
    forecastService.getForecast(coordinate.lat, lon: coordinate.lon) {
        (let currently) in

        if let currentWeather = currently {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
```

How would I be able to have the weather of the selected country updated.  I understand that I need to get access to the coordinates in the TableViewController. So how can I do this in the function Retrieve Weatherforecast?

Comment: To me it seems like this like `(segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController).coordinateItem = location` already does what you want, since it sets the coordinateItem of the destination view to be the coordinates that belong to the selected cell. Are you getting an error with this? Or is it just not producing the results you desire?

Comment: The problem is that the weather result is the same for each city.  I know it must have something to do with this function `unc retrieveWeatherForecast() {
        let forecastService = ForecastService(APIKey: forecastAPIKey)
        forecastService.getForecast(coordinate.lat, lon: coordinate.lon) {
            (let currently) in ` as it receives a variable `var coordinate: (lat: Double, lon: Double) = (37.8267,-122.423)` I understand the coorindates are hard coded here. But how would you get the array in this function?